# How to get all possible combinations at a column level

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe which is subset of my larger dataframe.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'item':['a','a','a','b','b','a','b','a','a','b','a','b','a','a','b'],
                  'country':['in','in','in','in','in','in','us','us','us','us','us','uk','uk','uk','uk'],
                  'timeframe':['sep-23','oct-23','nov-23','dec-23','q3\'23','q1\'23','sep-23','jul-23','aug-23','q2\'23','q1\'23','jul-23','aug-23','oct-23','sep-23'],
                  'value':[10,23,26,46,21,34,65,87,56,43,32,16,10,74,85]})
```

```
df

   item country timeframe   value
0   a   in       sep-23      10
1   a   in       oct-23      23
2   a   in       nov-23      26
3   b   in       dec-23      46
4   b   in       q3'23       21
...
7   a   us       jul-23      87
8   a   us       aug-23      56
9   b   us       q2'23       43
```

There are different time frames for each country and item and there can be missing timeframes for few countries per item.
Where ever there is a missing timeframe I want to include it with `NaN` value. For each item the minimum date or quarter will be starting point. In the dataframe, for item `a` country `in` doesn't have fields for q2'23, jul-23 and aug-23 similarly `us` doesn't have values for q3'23 and so on.
Similarly for item `b` `uk` doesn't have quarterly data (minimum quarter is q2'23 where US has values).

I tried using `MultiIndex.from_product` but irrespective of `item` this is creating product of all combinations. But I would need combinations at each item level.

```py
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['item'].unique(),df['country'].unique(),df['timeframe'].unique()], names=('item','country','timeframe'))

mux.to_frame().reset_index(drop=True).merge(df,on=['item','country','timeframe'],how='outer')
```

One possible solution that I could think of is creating list of unique `item` and using for loop filtering each item and then using `MultiIndex` which could serve the purpose but there must be a better way to handle this.

**Edit:**
The question is marked as duplicate but the answers provided there gives me combinations of all columns but I need combinations of each item which I couldn't get.

**PS:** Please feel free to mark it as duplicate if there is an answer already provided.

Comment: why don't you use `"` as string separator, no need to use backslash

Comment: There are several methods (see duplicate). If you don't mind installing a helper library, `janitor`'s `complete` is ideal for that.

Comment: Since the question is closed here is my answer: items = df["item"].unique()
countries = df["country"].unique()
min_timeframes = df.groupby("item")["timeframe"].min().reset_index()

ref_df = pd.DataFrame()
for item in items:
    item_df = pd.DataFrame({"item": [item] * len(countries), "country": countries})
    ref_df = pd.concat([ref_df, pd.merge(item_df, min_timeframes[min_timeframes["item"] == item], on="item", how="outer")])

result_df = pd.merge(ref_df, df, on=["item", "country", "timeframe"], how="left")
result_df = result_df.loc[:, ~result_df.columns.duplicated()]

Comment: @mozway As I already mentioned  in the question, these are giving all combinations which is what I do not want. I will need the possible combinations for each item.